# React-Redux: How to access value with JSON object, returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, undefined

Currently working on a project that calls an API and puts it into an array with one object inside. I'm trying to access a value within the array but I keep getting that the array is undefined. See below:

function in redux that gets the names of the items added to the cart

```
const addedNames = (state = initialState.addedIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1 ) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.productTitle]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const getAddedNames = state => state.addedNames
```

index file that calls the function getAddedNames

```
const getAddedNames = (state, id) => fromCart.getAddedNames(state.cart, id)
```

function that actually generates "names"

```
export const listProductNames = state =>
  getAddedIds(state).map(id => ({
    ...getProduct(state, id),
    //names: (getAddedNames(state, id)[1].value),
    names: (getAddedNames(state, id))
  }))
```

First item gets added to cart and pops into names:

```
const names = [{"id":1,"title":"Necklace","price":200.00,"inventory":1,"names":[null]}]
```

Later, I try using it in a React Component, file is called Cart.js

```
import { listProductNames } from '../reducers' //this should import the function listProductNames along with the array it returns, which is "names"

const CartContainer = ({ names }) => (
    <Cart 
       names = {names[0]["title"]}
    />
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

When I console.log names to the screen, it just passes an empty array

```
[]
```

How can I access the data in "names"? Also I can't quite understand how "names" is undefined when it is clearly an array with a object inside.

Comment: I suspect the issue is not in the code you're showing us. I think you need to show us the context in which names is defined and where <Cart> is used. You're not, for example, actually looking at names[0].names[0].title, are you?

Comment: @KevinRaoofi you're correct. I edited my code just now with some additional code that I'm using in other areas of my React app.

Comment: Please, show us where your <Cart> is defined, so we can check how names is arriving. and to help on debugging, add just before <Cart>: `{(() => console.log(names)) () }`

Comment: As names is a prop of <CartContainer>, it should be nice to see the code that is using <CartContainer names={something} /> to track from where the names prop comes from.

Comment: Which `names` is being passed to `CartContainer`? It's confusing to have a variable `names` to hold an array with a object that has properties `names`. I suspect a wrong `names` is being passed to the CartContainer.

Comment: We need to see your `connect` call to understand where `names` comes from.